# How to dynamically add and remove html element with javascript in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

I had this to dynamically add items in html

```
<td id="campus_list">
  <%= link_to_function image_tag("new.png", :width => 16) do |page|
    page.insert_html :bottom, 'campus_list', :partial => 'campus_selection'
  end %>
  <br/>
</td>
```

the template is like this

```
<div>
  <%= select_tag "campuses[]", options_for_select(AvailableCampuses.map{|item| [name, id]})) %>
  <%= link_to_function image_tag("destroy.png", :width => 16), "" %>
</div>
```

Since I do not know how to add unique id to each rendered div, I can not figure out how to remove each div using link_to_function.

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$(this).up('div').remove();` As the javascript in the `link_to_function` helper.
What it does is

1. fetch the link node (`$(this)`)
2. traverse the dom tree up until a div element is found (`up('div')`)
3. and remove said element (`remove()`)